# Using open source code LiveCharts to get a scatter plot that is created programmatically but I can't get a plot

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

I'm trying to use open source code LiveCharts to get a scatter plot that is created programmatically but I get an error object  reference not set to an object.

It is aborting in LiveCharts when I "show" the window. I'm new to LiveCharts and particularly the scatter plot. I can generate the scatter plot example that relies on the XAML file but I want more flexibility to plot a variety of graphs programatically.

I'm trying to use open source code LiveCharts to get a scatter plot that is created programmatically but I get an error object  reference not set to an object.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using LiveCharts;
using LiveCharts.Defaults;
using LiveCharts.Wpf;
using LiveCharts.Charts;

namespace TestScatterPlot01
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ChartValues<ObservablePoint> ValuesA { get; set; }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ValuesA = new ChartValues<ObservablePoint>();
            for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                double x = (double)i;
                double y = (double)(i * i);
                ValuesA.Add(new ObservablePoint(x, y));
            }
            CartesianChart theChart = new CartesianChart();
            theChart.LegendLocation = LegendLocation.Bottom;
            ScatterSeries s1 = new ScatterSeries();
            s1.Title = "Series A";
            s1.Values = ValuesA;
            s1.PointGeometry = DefaultGeometries.Diamond;
            theChart.AddToView(s1);
            Content = theChart;
            this.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

XAML file (I had to reconstruct this as TestScatterPlot03. The .cs file now has the namespace TestScatterPlot03).

```
<Window x:Class="TestScatterPlot03.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestScatterPlot03"

        xmlns:lvc="clr-namespace:LiveCharts.Wpf;assembly=LiveCharts.Wpf"

        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: you are using wpf, could you show your xaml file?

Comment: There's not much to the XAML file since I'm trying to do everything in the c# code.

Comment: <Window x:Class="TestScatterPlot03.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestScatterPlot03"
        xmlns:lvc="clr-namespace:LiveCharts.Wpf;assembly=LiveCharts.Wpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>